# Apache HTTP Client Fluent

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

Hi I want to use Apache HTTP Client Fluent to create a request to download a file. I need to add Autorization Basic Auth to the request to pass in a username and password which I can't find a good example of how to do.

I can see a addHeader method but can't find good examples of how to construct it. Thanks!

So far the code i have is:

```
String auth = username + ":"+ token
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes());
String encodedAuth = new String(encodedBytes)
URL downloadFileURL = new URL (urlbuild)

Executor executor = Executor.newInstance();
executor.execute(Request.Get(downloadFileURL.toURI())
 .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encodedAuth )
 .connectTimeout(1000))
  .saveContent(new File(mobileAppPath + System.getProperty("file.separator") + mobileApp.name));
```

Comment: But I get the Exception: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was due to Java trying to validate the SSL certificate i used Java code below to trust all hosts before executing the request.
https://www.javatips.net/api/java.security.cert.x509certificate